# Inference and training versions of TF graphs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

What is the recommended way to generate graphs for use at inference time vs. training time? Basically, for training, the graph would require all sorts of components for data input and augmentation including some custom ops, while at inference time this whole subgraph can be replaced by a placeholder.

How should I typically set things up, if the goal is to minimize the size of the inference time model? I also wouldn't want to have to link in any of the custom ops used only for training.

My main concern is what is the "right" way of doing this. Basically to guarantee that I can use a tf.train.Saver() to restore the training graph into the inference graph without any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point to ensure that your inference graph does not have compatibility issues would be to use metagraph. There is a detailed tutorial available https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph.

1. The primary reason for recommending it is clear_devices flag available in the tf.train.import_meta_graph which can be used to remove device dependencies from your checkpoints.
2. Other benefits would include the ability to retrieve hyper-parameters used during training and saving interesting operations (input placeholder) in collection for easy retrieval.
3. It also helps with code re-usability as you can write an inference function that does not incorporate graph definition but uses metagraph to load the same. I found this very helpful if I am training a model that is validated during training and used as feature extractor too.